# How remove(Object o, Object[] snapshot, int index) of CopyOnWriteArrayList class is implemented?

Tags: java

i dont understand how ***findindex*** is calculated here, i have never seen something like this. please explain the below code .

```
private boolean remove(Object o, Object[] snapshot, int index) {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        Object[] current = getArray();
        int len = current.length;
        if (snapshot != current) findIndex: {
            int prefix = Math.min(index, len);
            for (int i = 0; i < prefix; i++) {
                if (current[i] != snapshot[i] && eq(o, current[i])) {
                    index = i;
                    break findIndex;
                }
            }
            if (index >= len)
                return false;
            if (current[index] == o)
                break findIndex;
            index = indexOf(o, current, index, len);
            if (index < 0)
                return false;
        }
        Object[] newElements = new Object[len - 1];
        System.arraycopy(current, 0, newElements, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy(current, index + 1,
                         newElements, index,
                         len - index - 1);
        setArray(newElements);
        return true;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

- also what **break findIndex ;** does?
- What do you call this type of functionality and when was it introduced?
- findIndex is a variable or method or something like static block ? what type is it?

Comment: see [branching statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"findIndex" is a *label*, and the corresponding break breaks "up to" that label.

In other words: this is a mechanism that allows you to continue / break an *outer* loop from within a nested loop!

This is just a more powerful version of ordinary break / continue. It is rarely used, as it can quickly increase the complexity of your code (basically it breaks the single entry / single exit principle in structured programming).

From that perspective, it is the Java version of a *goto* command.